# bad practice? what's it 'called'

Tags: php

in PHP, I'm considering doing something like this:

```
function foo(){
echo 'bar';
}

$fn = 'foo';

$fn();
```

It works, but is it considered bad practice?

I have an multidimensional array of elements that each have a corresponding function. I would like to store that function name, and call the corresponding functions for each element when traversing the array.

something like:

```
function render_el1(){ echo 'et';}
function render_el2(){ echo 'to';}

$elements = array(
    'el_1' => array(
        'name' => 'Element One'
    ,   'func' => 'render_el1'
    )
,   'el_2' => array(
        'name' => 'Element Two'
    ,   'func' => 'render_el2'
    )
);


foreach($elements as $element => $options){
    $fn = $options['func'];

    echo '<h1>'.$options['name'].'</h1>';

    if (function_exists($fn)) {
        $fn();
    }
}
```

Any comments to this approach is highly welcome, and I'd also like to know what this method is called in programming terms.

Comment: I'd be very tempted to call it reflectionesque evil, but I'm not sure that's answer material :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure it is *bad practice*, but **it makes your code hard to understand** : to understand your short *(5 lines)* example, I've had to think :-(

Using [**`call_user_func()`**](https://www.php.net/call_user_func) and other functions of the same kind could have at least one advantage : looking at the code, one would immediatly understand you are calling a function in a way that's not the one we're generally used to.

Comment: It does obfuscate the real intention very well!

Comment: Thanks I see. call_user_func() is of course the better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to register functions into an array in your second example and then call them for what looks like a render process. This is similar to using function pointers in C (or paint event callbacks etc). It is an *okay* approach if you don't want to/can't use polymorphism (*the* feature that makes OOP worthwhile).

Your approach is simpler at that stage, but will probably get more bloated if you are adding more sophisticated code.

Comment: thanks, you're right, its a render process. I can't use polymorphism as I'm not (yet) familiar with it, but I'll look into what it is. It may be too much for my current (WordPress Theme) project, as this is rather simple.

Comment: so for anyone else stumbling across this: here is a nice tutorial for beginners: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php/